# R: agrep error when replacing string with another string

Tags: string, r, replace, agrep

after a lot of trial/error and the search function I am still somewhat clueless about an I-thought-simple-thing (as always, hrmpf):

I have a column in a data frame `x$question` and within that column, there is an expression `'A/V'` every once in a while, and I simply want it to be changed to `'A / B'`.

I tried a little here and there, and thought this should work:

```
 x$question[agrep('A/V',x$question)]<-'A / B'
```

but I get the error:

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, agrep('A/V',  :
invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

*or I could do this*

```
agrep('A/V','A / B', x$question).
```

But here I get the error:

```
Error in .amatch_bounds(max.distance) : 
match distance components must be non-negative
```

Since I am quite out of ideas, I would be very thankful, if you had a suggestions, or maybe an even simpler way of replacing a string with another string.

Comment: Your data is a `factor`, either convert to `character` or modify the `levels` instead. Provide an example and I will demonstrate how.

Comment: Hi James, and thanks! - I knew it, damn factor****. Shouldn't `levels(x$question["A/V"])<-"A / B"` work, though? (which it doesn't). Am I still missing something? - I'll upload a small file with an example, just a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
 gsub("A/V","A/B",x$question)
```

Example:

```
x<-c("A/V", "A/V", "A/V")
x<-gsub("A/V","A/B",x)
>x
[1] "A/B" "A/B" "A/B"
```

Note: You can use `ifelse` for that too.

```
> ifelse(x=="A/B","A/V",x)
[1] "A/V" "A/V" "A/V"
```

Comment: Well, it kind of does and does not - it puts out the levels (with the now correctly changed expression), but does not change the data!

Comment: Just assigned it to column you want to replace like `x<-gsub("A/V","A/B",x)` and it will replace all.